# EC2 instance in IPv6-only subnet has no public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The VPC for my instance has DNS hostnames enabled, but the instance does not have a public DNS hostname. I need to test hostname resolution in IPv6-only environments, but instances do not seem to be assigned a public DNS hostname.

I created an EC2 instance with ipv6-only. It was assigned an ipv6 address, but no hostname. When I do a DNS-reverse lookup, the lookup is unsuccessful.

And what is the use for private DNS hostnames? Can they be reached/pinged from other instances or machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable [Resource-Based DNS hostnames](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-ipv6-only-subnets-and-ec2-instances/) for IPv6-only EC2 instances. This will use the instance ID for the hostname, instead of the IP address.

Note however that this is **only** for private DNS hostnames. Public DNS hostnames are not supported for IPv6-only EC2 instances.

Comment: What are private DNS hostnames used for? Can they be reached/pinged by other instances or machines?

Comment: Private DNS would be usable by other EC2 instances in the same VPC.